# Reveal all favourites in new tab page on macOS Safari

Tags: macos, safari, mojave

MacOS Safari just updated itself to 13.0

Now when I open a new tab it shows me only two rows from my favourites.

View > Show favourites bar... shows me all of my favourites.

How do I get the new tab page to show me a grid of all of my favourites, as it did before the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a "Show more" button at the top-right:

[image]

But I couldn't see it in full-screen Safari because I have View > Always Show Toolbar in Fullscreen unchecked:

[image]

The slide-out toolbar was covering up the title and "show more" button on the page.

There are multiple ways to reveal them:

- Open a Safari window that isn't full-screened
- In the new tab page, drag one of the favicons and then put it back in the same spot. The toolbar disappears.
- Check View > Always Show Toolbar in Fullscreen